# RealmBase Encryption Issue

Tags: classpath, tomcat7, server.xml

i am trying to encrypt password for server.xml using RealmBase 
into Tomcat7 through below command:

```
java -cp bin\tomcat-juli.jar;lib\catalina.jar;lib\tomcat-util.jar; org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a SHA passwd
```

and I am facing below error on executing the comman:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0>java -cp bin\tomcat-juli.jar;lib\catalina.jar;lib\tomcat-util.jar; org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a  MD5 passwd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including `servlet-api.jar` as well.

```
java -cp bin\tomcat-juli.jar;lib\catalina.jar;lib\tomcat-util.jar;lib\servlet-api.jar org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a SHA passwd
```

**EDIT**

After trying to run this myself, there was yet another class missing. Instead of including every JAR in the classpath manually, I decided it would be easier to just include them all with `lib\*`. Try this...it works for me!

```
java -cp bin\tomcat-juli.jar;lib\* org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a SHA passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick response was working on same
tried below with servlet-api.jar

Comment: Did it work when you replaced the individual `lib\...` entries with `lib\*`?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/HexUtils

Comment: Below is my command which I used & working fine
`java -cp bin\*;lib\* org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a SHA passwd`

Thankx